# Unable to Split by ":[" in Java

Tags: java, split

I have 2 nested HashMaps as a String which I am trying to parse.

My String is as follows :

```
"20:[cost:431.14, Count:19, Tax:86.228"
```

Therefore I need to Split by "`:[`" in order to get my key, `20`, For some reason I'm not able to do this.

I have tried :

`myString.split(":[")` and `myString.split("\\:[")` but neither seem to work.

Can anyone detect what I have wrong here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `String.split` use regex, `[` should be escaped, not `:`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to escape the character `[` , but not the  character `:` like below:

```
String str = "20:[cost:431.14, Count:19, Tax:86.228";
String[] spl = str.split(":\\[");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why we need to skip [ in the first place?

Comment: @Yash it is clear because `[` used to define the opening of a Character Classes in regular expression, and split use regex so you have to escape it to consider `[` as a literal character check here https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: It should be mentioned that there're *two* chars being eacaped: the `[` and the \. That's why the full escape sequence is `\\[` rather than just `\[` as one might expect whenever common escape sequences, such as `\n`, are used.

Answer (score 6):

[`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) use regex.

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

You need to escape `[` since this is a "reserved" character in regular expresionn, not `:`

```
myString.split(":\\[")
```

Not that you could/should set a limit if you only want the first cell

```
myString.split(":\\[", 2);
```

This will return an array of 2 cell, so after the first occurence, it doesn't need to read the rest of the `String`. (This is not really necessary but good to know).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to automatically escape your string

```
String string = "20:[cost:431.14, Count:19, Tax:86.228";
String[] split = string.split(Pattern.quote(":["));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

> Therefore I need to Split by ":[" **in order to get my key, 20**. For
>   some reason I'm not able to do this.

In this case you can use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with some regex to get this input so you can use :

```
String str = "20:[cost:431.14, :[Count:19, Tax:86.228";
String result = str.replaceAll("(.*?):\\[.*", "$1");// output 20
```

#### regex demo

---

If the key is just an integer you can use `(\d+):\[` check [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP7BYD/2)

Answer (score 1):

be noted `'['`  character is special character in regular expression so you have to make an escape character like `\\`  `str.split(":\\[");` and remember the string is immutable so if do you want to use it twice you have to reassign it with split like this `String[] spl =str.split(":\\[");`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you just need the key "20" in your `String` is to substring it to get the part before the delimiter.

```
String key = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(":["));
```